# Given a set of m numbers {1,2,...m} we can always select a subset having sum of [1,m(m+1)/2]

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Given a set s of m numbers {1,2,3,4,....m} i need to prove that given any number x in the interval [1,m(m+1)/2] i can select a subset s' from the set s such that sum of elements in s' is equal to x.
My approach was to consider two cases:
1) 1<=x<=m
In this case s' is just a singleton set containing x

2)m<x<= (m*(m+1))/2
In this case i first find the greatest integer 'i' such that x - [m+(m-1)+(m-2)+(m-3).....(m-i)] is positive. Let this quantity be c = x - [m+(m-1)+(m-2)+(m-3).....(m-i)] . Now because of the way we have defined 'i' , if we subtract m-i-1 from c we will get a non positive value. 
 This means that c-(m-i-1)<=0.
This means that  c<=(m-i-1).
Also 0<=c. 
if c=0 we have,
c = x - [m+(m-1)+(m-2)+(m-3).....(m-i)] = 0.
This means x = m+(m-1)+(m-2)+(m-3).....(m-i)
And we can select s' containing elements m,(m-1),(m-2),(m-3).....(m-i).
but if c is not equal to 0,
Then we know that 1<=c<=(m-i-1), We can select this value of c.
This means we can select s' as m,(m-1),(m-2),(m-3).....(m-i), c 
Is this proof correct??
How can this be proved using induction??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An induction proof.

For $m=1$ the result is trivial.

Suppose the result is true for $S=\{1,2, ... , k\}$ and now consider the numbers up to $k+1$. If a sum up to $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ is required then you can just use a subset of $S$. So suppose you require a total sum, $T$, greater than this.  Then $$\frac{k(k+1)}{2}<T\le \frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}.$$
Then $$T-(k+1)\le \frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}-(k+1)=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$ and so a subset of $S$ has total sum $T-(k+1)$ and then adding $k+1$ to this subset gives a set with total $T$.

Answer (score 0):

Notation: $[m]=\{1,2,\dots,m\}$; for $S\subseteq[m]$ we write $\sum S=\sum_{n\in S}n$; in particular $\sum[m]=1+2+3+\cdots+m=m(m+1)/2$.

Let $m$ be a positive integer. Let $P(x)$ denote the statement: there is a set $S\subseteq[m]$ with $\sum S=x$. I will show by induction that $P(x)$ holds for every integer $x$ such that $1\le x\le\sum[m]$.

$P(1)$ is clear; take $S=\{1\}$.

Suppose $P(x)$ holds for some fixed $x\lt\sum[m]$; I have to show that $P(x+1)$ holds. Choose a set $S\subseteq[m]$ such that $\sum S=x$. Let $n$ be the least positive integer that does not belong to $S$. Since $\sum S\lt\sum[m]$, we must have $n\le m$. If $n=1$ let $S'=S\cup\{1\}$; if $n\gt1$ let $S'=(S\setminus\{n-1\})\cup\{n\}$. In either case, $S'\subseteq[m]$ and $\sum S'=\sum S+1=x+1$, so $P(x+1)$ holds.